# Get a file meta data object in Node

Tags: node.js

Is there a way to get a file object in Node with file meta data like mimetype, originalname, path, etc..? I'd like to read a file from disk and get this information, rather than a Buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one nodejs package that could help you work with file meta data information.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-meta

Comment: Take a look at this example here
https://code-maven.com/system-information-about-a-file-or-directory-in-nodejs